# Help resoldering SMD capacitor

Tags: capacitor, soldering, surface-mount, gpu

I was cleaning my 1080 and installing new thermal pads when I accidently broke off a capacitor during disassembly.

Does anyone have experience resoldering SMD capacitors on GPUs and if so what solder do you use and what type of hot tweezers work best?

In the picture I've attached you can see there is some copper showing so I think my best bet would be to remove the older solder with copper wicking, tin the copper contacts and then resolder the capacitor.

Any advice for resoldering SMD components would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You can just use a normal iron, leaded 63/37 rosin-core solder, tweezers, and liquid flux. The real problem is a GPU board probably has lots of copper layers which makes it act as a heatsink. Without a preheater, it will be difficult to get the solder to melt without frying something else but preheaters tend to be overpriced to begin with and you don't want a crap preheater. It's not particularly difficult but with no experience you will not know how much is too much. Do not attempt without plenty of practice on other boards that also have lots of copper layers.

Comment: The first time you are going to run into this will also be the most severe: When you use the copper braid to clean up the pads since you will be trying to heat up lead-free solder which has a higher melting temperature, *and* the heatsinking copper braid *and* the heatsinking PCB. You will want a big chisel tip iron. Double the width of the pad if you can fit it in. I can't really tell you in words how much is too much. If you need to hold the iron for longer than 3-5 seconds to get the solder to melt, back off and change your method. Beyond 3 seconds is getting dicey already.

Comment: @DKNguyen What temperature do you recommend for removing the old solder? Also, would it be a good idea to instead use hot air with solder paste and cover the surrounding components with kapton tape?

Comment: To remove the old solder, 300C since it is lead-free solder. For the new solder, 250C since it is leaded. If that is not enough then you need preheater or a bigger tip or both. No. you do not heat solder paste or hot air or kapton tape or any of that.

Comment: i think this may help you to replace that and put it back
https://youtu.be/TZsvvUWUInE?t=208

Comment: You should be able to get a good idea if your technique is ok just wicking off the old lead free, which will actually be harder to flow than new leaded solder.  I would try and remove it and if you can't, look into a better iron and/or flux.  Those planes are pretty small though, so this shouldn't be too hard with even a sub $100 iron.

Comment: Silver bearing solder is recommended for soldering chip components to reduce leaching of silver from the chip terminations. For resoldering one part that's been torn off the board it probably won't matter that much though.

Comment: Do not use a hot air gun, this will destroy your board for sure. Even a proper hot air soldering station is harder to control than a soldering iron at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it that way:

- get a chisel tip for your soldering iron.
- if it's adjustable, set it on about 350°C and wait until it's really hot, not just "hot enough to start melting solder".
- I would not remove the existing solder because it's already making a nice capacitor-sized bed that fits the part.
- put the capacitor in place and practice holding it down firmly but gently with a thin piece of wood or some strong thin cardboard with your non-dominant hand. Rotate the board so it feels comfortable.
- collect a blob of solder about 1 mm deep on the tip of the iron
- touch the solder to one side of the capacitor and hold it for up to 2 seconds.
- remove the iron, but keep holding the capacitor down another five seconds.
- repeat for the other side. You should not need to hold down the capacitor this time.

Check for shorts. Be careful to not touch the neighbouring parts with the iron while doing this. And don't aim for perfection -- stop when the two solder joints look continuous, even if they're not the most beautiful shape or if the capacitor is a little tilted ;)

Comment: If leaving the existing solder in place, you should apply external flux. There's a reason why it fell off in the first place - the reason could as well be bad/polluted solder paste as anything else. I'd clean it up and re-do the joint from scratch.

Comment: "a thin piece of wood"  Eeh? How about holding it down with the ESD tweezers that are mandatory for this kind of work?

Answer (score 2):

It may not be too difficult since the planes aren’t that extensive and have relatively few vias.  However it will almost certainly have been assembled using lead-free solder which is rather more difficult to work with.  Start by running the pads and if possible the capacitor with leaded solder.  If you have a temperature-controlled iron I’d get it fairly hot, maybe 380C.  With a powerful iron you might be able to melt both pads at once but more likely you’ll need to do one and then the other.  The most important thing is to make sure you don’t end up with solder shorting the pads.  If you don’t end up with a nice shiny blob on each pad you can clean up by applying some flux and re-melting the joint for a moment.  If you don’t have flux then you can add more solder as this is flux-cored.  If the soldering iron’s tip is reasonably clean it will tend to pick up excess solder.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no previous experience of soldering, then I'd simply advise to back off from this, since SMD soldering is metaphorically equivalent to "jumping in at the deep end before learning to swim". You will almost certainly not get it right and GFX cards are sensitive - you can easily damage the board. Practice on through-hole boards first.

Assuming you have some soldering experience, then:

- These GFX card are often very sensitive to electro-static shocks (ESD). Avoid touching the board with your bare hands, or at least always touch the metal frame next to the connectors the first thing you do, since it will be chassis grounded but not sensitive to ESD.
- Necessary equipment:

  - Solder iron, temperature at 350°C.
  - Small tip. You can use a flat tip since this appears to be a "huge" 1206 component. For smaller SMD work (0805 or smaller) you'd use a narrow, conical tip - I prefer the bent ones.
  - ESD tweezers
  - Wick braid
  - Flux pen or equivalent. "No clean" flux!
  - 0.25mm solder wire. Leaded solder is easier to work with, no big deal if you only got RoHS solder. Don't use some elephant-sized solder wire though, that will only mess things up. Again, also make sure to only use "no clean" flux core.
- Remove the old joint with the wick braid first. There's a reason the component fell off in the first place. Cold joint, too little paste, too little flux, who knows. I'd suspect a cold joint though, since the cap appears to be sitting between two large copper planes.
- Manually apply flux to remove oxidation/pollution.
- Hold down the body of the cap with your tweezers, apply a bit of of solder on one side but for now focus on getting the component aligned correctly and fixed to the board, rather than making a perfect solder joint. (This might be hard at first if those copper planes absorb a lot of the heat.)
- Solder the opposite pad but this time look for proper wetting.
- Re-visit the first pad and do the joint proper.
- If you mess up, then apply more flux manually and re-do the joint without adding more solder. Particularly if you get small "antennas" forming at the joint from where you removed the iron. This means that all the flux core vaporized at the first attempt, which is very common.